# Ansible: How would I insert a text string in the middle of a conf file using an Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I need to add text stating 'Allow all' right underneath 'Order allow,deny'
So this:

```
# Restrict access to the server...
<Location />
  Order allow,deny
</Location>
```

Should look like this:

```
# Restrict access to the server...
<Location />
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>
```

My Ansible playbook block looks like this so far:

```
  - name: Enable access to the server                                                                                                                                                                     
    lineinfile:
      destfile: /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to unconditionally "*insert a text string in the middle of a conf file using an Ansible playbook*".

Ansible `lineinfile` module lets you ensure that a particular line exists in a file and if it doesn't, it will insert it before (`insertbefore`) or after (`insertafter`) another line, but even if it works in a specific case, it is a specific case (with the condition: the line does not already exist elsewhere in the file).

This might be acceptable for flat configuration files, but it gets troublesome if a file is structured (with sections which might contain the same line).

---

The bottom line is: you should avoid making the code dependent on an unspecified initial state, so use the [`template` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html) instead.

In rare cases where it is impossible, define the whole section with [`blockinfile` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/blockinfile_module.html), for example:

```
- blockinfile:
    path: /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
    marker: # Ansible-managed block { mark }
    block: |
      <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow all
     </Location>
```

Comment: I tried this and it inserts the block at the bottom of the file

Comment: The only differnce is that because i am using Ansible 2.2, I had to use destfile rather than path

Comment: Of course it does insert the block at the bottom by default. That's why I stated you should use `template`. The suggestion for `blockinfile` was for some specific cases, but you need to know, what you are doing and build the file step by step.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `insertafter` parameter of the `lineinfile` module (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html)

something like this :

```
- lineinfile:
    path: /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
    insertafter: '\sOrder allow,deny'
    line: '\nAllow all'
```